# Postback Issue With Objects In ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, click, postback

I have some buttons on a web form in my ASP.NET project. The end user has to interact with these buttons like you would with a calculator. My issue is that ever time the end user clicks a button the page is refreshed because of postback. I tried to turn postback off like so:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   protected void btn7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                       
        const string stringNumber7 = "7";
        var text = txtNumber.Text;
        text += stringNumber7;
        txtNumber.Text = text;
        CheckMaxLength(); 
    }
}
```

But then the click event will not fire. I have tried using images, image buttons, image maps. I can't get the result I want from those object either. I would like to be able to stop postback, but still have my button click event to fire like the would in a windows app. I have see some forums talking using a update panel. I am not sure how to implement an update panel correctly.  I am not familiar with AJAX controls.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish want I want to do using an update panel? Or how to stop postback and still fire server side code?

Comment: A postback means that the client posts back to the server, so if you want to handle a button-click event on the server you have to go this way. If you want to use javascript to handle the click event on the clientside use a html-input type=button and handle it's `onclick` event.

Comment: you can use JavaScript or jQuery  if you don't want postback.

Comment: I think you have a basic misunderstanding... the only way server side code can be invoked after a button click is via a PostBack. That is fundamental. If you want to preserve values on the screen, you will need to place them in a control that either maintains state or (if not), you will need to rebuild those server side.

Comment: @andleer Thank you for your comment. Can you elaborate on "control that either maintains state"? Which control are you referring too?

Answer (score 0):

If the `botton` is invoking local / client side JavaScript, return false within the control event attribute which will cancel the PostBack.

```
<button onclick="MyMethod();return false;">Click Me</button>
```

of if you are using a server side control:

```
<asp:button runat="server" OnClientClick="MyMethod();return false;" />
```

Comment: The "MyMethod()" does that have to be a separate method, or can I use the button's click event?

Comment: You don't make it clear from your description if you are invoking JavaScript as a result of your button click. You say the button is causing a PostBack... what code do you want it to run? If that code is client side, you will need to cancel the PostBack by returning false. If that code is server side, you can only get to it via a PostBack. Your button needs some method of calling the code if it is client side. You can do that using the onclick attribute or use a library such as jQuery to wire up the click event.